# How to construct NSDirectionalEdgeInsets struct

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uikit, ios11

How do I construct a NSDirectionalEdgeInsets struct in iOS 11 ?

Is there any make helpers like UIEdgeInsetsMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the make method for this in ObjectiveC:

```
NSDirectionalEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat leading, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat trailing)
```

and in Swift:

```
NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat, leading: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, trailing: CGFloat)
```